# Sort records based on country from xml using php

Tags: php, xml, sorting

i have one excelsheet i write data and export it in to xml data and got xml format like below now i parse this record using php usign below code but i have one country dropdown i want to display this record based on selected country means display the record which i get in post using php dropdown,but as no parent child relation ship i can to it so is there any way to do so?

```
 <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Dr. nair</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">12121 brok Blvd. </Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">WEST INDIES</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">WI</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">90025</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">310-444-1212</Data></Cell>
   </Row>

   <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Dr. july</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Paldi. </Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">WEST INDIES</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">WI</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">90025</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">310-4544-1212</Data></Cell>
   </Row>


    <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Dr. lol</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Paldi. </Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">New Zeland</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">NZ</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">90025</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">310-4544-1212</Data></Cell>
   </Row>


    <Row>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Dr. nik</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">Paldi. </Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">India</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">IN</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="Number">90025</Data></Cell>
    <Cell><Data ss:Type="String">310-4544-1212</Data></Cell>
   </Row>



 $excel = new XML2003Parser('sample.xml');

    $table = $excel->getTableData();

    // display instruction

    echo "<table border=1>";

    $data=array();
    $data_city=array();
     foreach($table["table_contents"] as $row){

          $data[]=$row['row_contents'][3]['value'];
                  $data_city[]=$row['row_contents'][2]['value'];

        print_r($data);

    }
```